# casting from empty byte array to struct pointer can violate strict aliasing?

Tags: c, casting, memory-alignment, strict-aliasing

What most people are concerned about is what happens if they receive a byte array with data and they want to cast the array to a struct pointer - this can violate strict aliasing rules. I'm not sure whether initializing an empty byte array of sufficient size, casting it to a struct pointer, and then populate the struct members would violate the strict aliasing rules.

The details:
Say I have 2 packed structs:

```
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    char b[2];
    uint16_t c : 8;
    uint16_t d : 7;
    uint16_t e : 1;
} in_t;

typedef struct
{
    int x;
    char y;
} out_t;

#pragma pack()
```

**I have many types of in/out packed structs for different messages so please ignore the specific members I put for the example. The structs can contain bitfields, other structs, and unions. Also, endianess is taken care of. Also, I can't use new c standards (>= c99) features.**

I'm receiving a buffer containing `in_t` (the buffer is large enough to contain `out_t`, however big it'll be) as `void *`

```
void recv_msg(void *data)
{
    in_t *in_data = (in_t*)data;
    out_t *out_data = (out_t*)data;
    // ... do something with in_data then set values in out_t. 
    // make sure values aren't overwritten.
}
```

Now I have a new type of in struct

```
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    char b[3];
    uint32_t c;
} in_new_api_t;

typedef struct
{
    int x;
    char y[2];
} out_new_api_t;

#pragma pack()
```

Now, when moving to the new api but keeping the old api for backward compatibility, I want to copy values from the old `in_t` to `in_new_api_t`, use `in_new_api_t`, set values in `out_new_api_t`, and then copy the values to `out_t`.

The way I thought of doing it is to allocate an empty byte array the size of `max(sizeof(in_new_api_t), sizeof(out_new_api_t));`, cast it to `in_new_api_t *`, translate values from `in_t` to `in_new_api_t`, send the new api struct to the new api function, then translate values from `out_new_api_t` to `out_t`.

```
void recv_msg(void *data)
{
    uint8_t new_api_buf[max(sizeof(in_new_api_t), sizeof(out_new_api_t))] = {0};
    in_new_api_t *new_in_data = (in_new_api_t*)new_api_buf;

    in_t *in_data = (in_t*)data;

    // ... copy values from in_data to new_in_data
    // I'M NOT SURE I CAN ACCESS MEMBERS OF new_in_data WITHOUT VIOLATING STRICT ALIASING RULES. 

    new_in_data->a = in_data->a;
    memcpy(new_in_data->b, in_data->b, 2);
    // ...

    new_recv_msg((void*)new_in_data);

    out_new_api_t *new_out_data = (out_new_api_t*)new_api_buf;

    out_t *out_data = (out_t*)data;

    // ... copy values from new_out_data to out_data

}
```

**The point I'm just not sure about is whether casting from 'uint8_t []' to 'in_new_api_t  *' would violate the strict aliasing rules or cause any other issues. Also Access performance issues are a concern.**

And if so, what is the best solution?

I can make copies of in_t and `out_t` and make `in_new_api_t` point to `data` but then I need to copy the data 4 times to make sure I'm not overwriting values: from `data` to `in_t tmp_in`, from `tmp_in` to `in_new_api,` then from `out_new_api` to `out_t tmp_out` and from `tmp_out` to `out_t out`.

Comment: "Also, I can't use new c standards" Then why are you? `stdint.h` is not available pre C99. Which is hardly a "new" standard, it is 19 years old.

Comment: @Lundin minor nit-pick: I think `stdint.h` was in an addendum from 1996. Won't change the OP's caveat though, as I read it along the "I must use C90" interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is a couple of `union` types. The common initial sequences of the `struct` members of a `union` are layout-compatible, per the standard, and can be mapped onto each other, in exactly the same way as the family field of every `sockaddr_*` type.  Type-punning on a union is legal in C, but not in C++ (although it works with POD on every compiler, no compiler that tries to be compatible with existing code will ever break it, and any possible alternative is undefined behavior too).  This might possibly obviate the need for a copy.

A `union` is guaranteed to be properly-aligned for both. If you do use pointers, it is probably a good idea to `Alignas` the object to both types, just in case.

A `memcpy()` to and from arrays of `unsigned char` is also legal; the language standards call the contents of the array after the copy the object representation.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly straight-forward:

- Casting to a pointer-to-struct type, when the pointed-at data by the `void*` is of *any* different type, is a strict aliasing violation.
- Casting to a pointer-to-struct from a pointer to raw character buffer is a strict aliasing violation. (You may however go the other way around: from pointer-to-struct into pointer-to-char.)

So your code looks wildly unsafe and is also a bit confusing because of the void pointer. So number one is to get rid of that icky, dangerous void pointer! You can create a type such as:

```
typedef union
{
  in_t          old;
  in_new_api_t  new;
  uint8_t       bytes [sizeof(in_new_api_t)];
} in_api_t;
```

Then use this as parameter to your function.

This will first of all allow you to access the initial parts of each struct in a safe manner that doesn't violate aliasing (6.5.2.3, the rule about common initial sequence). That is, the members `a` and `b` will correspond to each other in both structs. The only thing you can't rely on is the members that aren't the same - those will have to be copied explicitly with memcpy.

Second, you can now use the `bytes` member when you need to serialize the data. If you write the "out" structures as unions in a similar manner, and they too contain a `bytes` member of exactly the same size, you can safely cast from one type to the other, without strict aliasing violations. This is allowed by C11 6.5:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>   - a type compatible with the effective type of the object
>   /--/
>   - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members

If your union is accessed by a pointer to union type, that includes a byte array of exactly the same size (a compatible type), then that's allowed.

Comment: You mean one can move members from union interpretation `old` to union interpretation `new` by the virtue of `memcpy()`? What if two members in `new` simply changed place in relation to `old`? No overwrite of one of them?

Comment: @Vroomfondel The common initial sequence doesn't need to be moved at all. How the rest of the data gets treated isn't specified, especially since you use non-standard bit-fields. So maybe "it will work" on your specific compiler - for fully portable code you need to do some sort of hard copy of that part. There's no pointer aliasing issues with this method though.

Comment: @chux Not when going from effective type character array, to struct. Only when taking pointer-to-anything and casting to pointer-to-characer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in `recv_msg()` clearly is undefined behaviour and will likely break your code some day, as the compiler is entitled to do whatever it wants when moving from `*in_data` to `*out_data`. Also, if the `void* data` argument doesn't come from either a `malloc()` (and cousins) or from an object that originally was an `in_t` then you have UB and alignment problems even there.

Your method to save RAM is extremely risky. Even if you are bold enough to ignore the more theoretical UB case of accessing memory with an illegal but correctly aligned type, you still will get problems as there simply is no guarantee that the order of operations of copying *in-place* from one struct to the other won't trash your data.